# Memory leak error while showing chartjs 2 graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js"
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2"

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend)

function Reports() {
  const [graph, setGraph] = useState({})

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "top",
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Chart.js Bar Chart",
      },
    },
  }

  const handleAllLeadsGenerated = () => {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `${serverUrl}/reports/leads`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("response: ", res)
        setGraph({
          labels: res.data.map((row) => {
            return row.firstname
          }),
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Leads Generation",
              data: res.data.map((row, index) => {
                return parseInt(row.countn)
              }),
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
            },
          ],
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error: ", err)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleAllLeadsGenerated()
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
        <ToastContainer position="top-right" autoClose={5000} hideProgressBar={false} newestOnTop closeOnClick rtl={false} pauseOnFocusLoss draggable pauseOnHover theme="colored" />
        <Tabs>
          <TabList>
            <Tab>Leads Generation</Tab>
            <Tab>Recuiters Report</Tab>
          </TabList>
          <TabPanel>
            <Row>
              <Col md="12">
                <Card>
                  <CardHeader style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <CardTitle tag="h4">Leads Info</CardTitle>
                    <Button onClick={handleAllLeadsGenerated}>Reload</Button>
                  </CardHeader>
                  <CardBody>{graph ? <Bar options={options} data={graph} /> : <Spinner animation="border" />}</CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </TabPanel>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Reports
```

I am trying to show a graph of no. of leads generated by a user. when I go this component its shows memory leak error(blank page, nothing renders).
But if I comment the `<Bar />` component in the CardBody, and then uncomment it, it shows the graph while reloading the page, or coming from another page gives the error.

First time loading the component or reloading the page:
[image: First time loading the component or reloading the page]

Commenting and uncommenting the Bar component line, after compiling the code again it shows the graph:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary

```
{graph ? <Bar options={options} data={graph} /> : <Spinner animation="border" />}
```

is always true since empty object is truthy, so it will try to render the Bar component without the data ready I suppose.

Try

```
{graph.length > 0 ? <Bar options={options} data={graph} /> : <Spinner animation="border" />}
```

Comment: nope, and graph is an object. I tried to check the length of its labels but same error.

Comment: Object.keys(obj).length > 0 solved the issue.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

```
{Object.keys(graph).length > 0 ? <Bar options={options} data={graph} /> : <Spinner animation="border" />}
```

This solved my issue.